# Fractional scaling a single application window in Gnome Shell

Tags: scripts, display-resolution, scaling, gnome-shell

I am seeking to up-scale a single application in Ubuntu 17.04, Gnome Shell 3.24.

In my concrete case, the motivation is unstable zoom functionality in [Franz](http://meetfranz.com/), but another reason could be older apps not designed for scaling to high resolution displays.

[This answer from superuser](https://superuser.com/a/1189909/314287) suggests using [this script](https://github.com/kaueraal/run_scaled) to up-scale. The script, however, minimally allows up-scaling by a factor 2, which is far too much. The script also makes use of the `xrandr` package, which is deemed obsolete by `apt-get`.

Is there a hack that will allow me to up-scale a single application window to, say, 120% of the original?

Comment: I'm not able to install the script's dependencies at the moment, but I don't see why it wouldn't allow a scaling factor less than 2 – did you try `/path/to/run_scaled --scale=1.2`? What's the output of this?

Comment: I tried, but to no avail. I don't remember the output. I removed the required as it didn't work.

Comment: I concur with @dessert. The manual page of `run_scaled` reads: “`--scale`  Sets the factor the application is scaled by. Fractional scales are supported. It is set to 2 by default.” If that’s not the case I recommend that you add the error message to your question and file a bug report on GitHub.

Comment: He, the commit on the help file mentioning fractional scaling was added 3 days after I posted this question. I'll give it another try.

Comment: @dessert It works :) Would you, as the benevolent watcher, like the answer credit?

Comment: @Rasmus I added an answer, please get back to me if it's not right on the mark – I'm glad we finally solved this! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Ubuntu 19.10, the following works for the application I now have in mind:

```
QT_SCALE_FACTOR=1.2 application
```

Possibly, one may also want to play around with the above in combination with `QT_AUTO_SCREEN_SCALE_FACTOR=1` and `QT_AUTO_SCREEN_SCALE_FACTOR=0`.

Answer (score 2):

The [run_scaled](https://github.com/kaueraal/run_scaled) script provides the following option:

```
--scale  Sets the factor the application is scaled by.
         Fractional scales are supported. It is set to 2 by default.
```

To change the scaling factor you need to run the script on the executable you wish to run scaled as e.g.

```
/path/to/run_scaled --scale=1.2 /path/to/application
```